# Get rid of text in between () in PHP

Tags: php

Say you have a string like this:

`This is a string (with parenthesis stuff)`

How would you change that to

`This is a string`

?

Answer (score 2):

Replace it:

```
preg_replace('/\(.*?\)/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex.

Replace `\([^)]*\)` with the empty string.

Note: If there's more than one pair of parenthesis this will replace the innermost one.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $string = "This is a string (with parenthesis stuff)";
  echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string); // 'ABC '
```

or you can do this also

```
  $str = "This is a string (with parenthesis stuff)";
  $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $str));
```